# How to position an element at the bottom of 1st page in a fixed position across all browsers when printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

https://jsfiddle.net/rzj5a9mk/1/
I have been struggling with this, I am trying to position an image, in specific coordinates, at the bottom of the 1st page when printing, across all browsers limited to IE11.

I can accomplish this in chrome, with a fixed height on the element. But this same height fluctuates across the browsers. So, I've came to using viewheight, and a height: 70vh, is good in chrome and safari but in firefox it's too short.

```
.containerDiv {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 70vh;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 48px;
  width: 290px;
}
<div class="containerDiv">
 <div class="otherthing"/>
 <div class="anotherThing"/>
<img class="img">
</div>
```

Comment: Please insert a code snippet so I can see the output

Comment: Can't really do that, that would be a lot of code. I could possibly show examples?

Comment: You could insert a code snippet of just the element you need help with

Comment: Well I did include the structure of html and css of element, do you want like a sandbox?

Comment: Yes that would work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzj5a9mk/1/ Here ya go